# issue in created json file

Tags: java, arrays, json

Hello I'm having problem with converting objects to json file.

```
private static void convertToJson() {
    Gson json = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

        try (FileWriter jsonFile = new FileWriter("userFile.json")) {
            for(User userToConvert : userList) {
                String jsonFormat = json.toJson(userToConvert);
                System.out.println(jsonFormat);
                jsonFile.write(jsonFormat);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

In created json file im getting this output

{"username":"user1","password":"user1","email":"user@user.com"}{"username":"user2","password":"user2","email":"user@user.com"}

second line is underlined and says: 
**JSON standard allows only one top=level value**

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: try outputting your JSON objects in the JSON array format instead

Comment: You're outputting invalid json. You need an array around that.

Comment: just add your `userToConvert` to an array and then call `json.toJson(usersArray)` and only write that to file.

Comment: @diginoise thank you very much ! it's working

Answer (score 1):

solution was :

```
private static void convertToJson() {
    Gson json = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
    List jsonArrayList = new ArrayList<User>();
        try (FileWriter jsonFile = new FileWriter("userFile.json")) {
            for(User userToConvert : userList) {
                jsonArrayList.add(userToConvert);
            }
            String usersArray = json.toJson(jsonArrayList);
            jsonFile.write(usersArray);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

works like a charm !